# CSS Transparent Image stretched over a Pattern

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can i stretch over a transparent image in one layer, and in the other keep the image size (because it supposed to be a pattern). this is my code.

```
div.someclass {    
background-image: url('someimage.png'), url('someimage2.jpg');
}
```

I can divide this div into two different elements one over the other but I'm animating (using jquery) them, so it would be a significant impact on performance.

What should I do?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the double quotes `"` invalidate the entire `background-image` property/declaration. (Or does it work?) -- Oh, it's just 1 double quote, so that's definitely a killer.

Comment: yee sorry, this code originally came from javascript (jquery), let me fix that

Comment: I'm not quite certain I understand what you mean.  Could you give some more information?

Comment: about the javascript? to change a css attribute in jquery you need to use the function $(something).css("attr", "value") and i guess i missed one " when i posted my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the scaling of backgrounds with [`background-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size):

```
div.someclass {    
    background-image: url('someimage.png'), url('someimage2.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%, 200px 200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
}
```

For support across older browsers you'll need to use [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: it so slow... what should i do besides scale down the image's resolution?

Comment: @hdmi3killer I don't know, if you want advice on the images you're going to have to upload them somewhere so we can take a look.

Comment: @hdmi3killer Those images look OK, are you sure it's the images that are causing the performance issue?

Comment: ye... but only when i use this: "background-size: 100% 100%, auto auto; background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;"

Comment: @hdmi3killer OK, I think you'll just have to wait for browsers to get faster unfortunately